# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I'm trying to get data from the firebase database. I'm getting this error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Try many methods but the error is still here.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _categoryProvider.category.snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError){
                return Text('Something went wrong..');
              }
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(document?.data()['image']),// error is on this line
                        ),
                        //title: Text(document.data()['category name']),
                        onTap: (){},
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                ),
              );
              }),
```

Here is CategoryProvider.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class CategoryProvider{
  CollectionReference category = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories');
}
```

Comment: I think the closing parentheses in in the wrong place`NetworkImage(document?.data())['image']`

Comment: Hy thanks for your time and answer. Now this is the error ```lib/widgets/category_list.dart:56:74: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'NetworkImage'.
 - 'NetworkImage' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(document?.data())['image'], ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you confused [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) with [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html). This is because there are two different `snapshots()` methods (one from the `Query` class and one from the `DocumentReference` class).

Change this:

```dart
children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
```

to this:

```dart
children: snapshot.data.docs.map((QueryDocumentSnapshot document) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the error does not solve by adding that line.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
final temp = document.data; // once try this and if it did not work use json.decode(document.data)
return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(temp['image']),// error is on this line
                        ),
                        //title: Text(temp['category name']),
                        onTap: (){},
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                ),
```

let me know the result.